# Responsive issue. Websites remains big while elements scale

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mobile, media-queries

I am currently working on making a website responsive. However i am experiencing an issue which i can't seem to figure out.

So, when you visit the website on a mobile phone or you just scale your browser, most of it ( it's not yet finished ) scales properly. And you can see that the elements on the homepage really all have the same width. Because I used Width 100% CSS property.

But, it's still possible to scroll sideways, there is this big background thing sitting in the way, and i can't figure out what is, my element inspector doesn't even seem to catch it as an element or whatsoever. I have been searching what it is, I thought maybe its a jQuery thing, but really none of anything i have tried seems to work. I also tried different viewports, but this doesn't seem to work either..

Does anybody have an idea what is going on here? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

Thanks everyone for helping out! The #access ID. Still had a width of 970px. I set it to 100% and it's al fixed now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to specify the viewport in your `<head>` area. This will make the responsiveness come into effect properly.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Read more about viewports here: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Along with that, there seem to be a couple of elements that you need to add to your responsive CSS as they have set widths in the style.css file.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #access {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #footer-sidebar { 
        padding: 5%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your time. I just tried this but it doesn't seem to work. I already had a viewport but removed it as testing to see if it worked. Forgot to put i back on though. Anyways, even with a viewport this problem still occurs.

Comment: Understood, will look into it. Seems like it could be a element which might still be holding its width. See my amended answer

Comment: I think it's the background image on the body element, in your CSS.

Comment: It's not @GuyH. If you look at the HTML, on line 220, there is the div #access. This doesn't get reset in the responsive.css file and therefore stays at 970px regardless of anything else. Just needs to be reset :)

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. The #access div was the problem. It's fixed now!

Answer (score 1):

try removing the width on style.css
 #access{}

EDIT: `#access {
    /* width: 970px; */
    margin: 9px auto 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 500;
    }`

Comment: Thanks alot raz! This was indeed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Remove dot from this pseudo class selector

```
.widget:after, #menu-footermenu:after, .clearfix:after {
  content: "";
}
```